# Getting the one AD Object that was modified within 15 minutes ago time interval maximum?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the list of the AD object which was created or modified in the past not older than 15 minutes ago.

How can I achieve it?

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage='The SamAccountName of the AD object to search')]
    $SamAccountName,
    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    $Server = (Get-ADDomainController -Filter "Name -eq '${env:ComputerName}'").HostName
)

$15MinutesAgo = New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

If ($adObject = Get-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($SamAccountName)'" -Server $Server -Properties * | Where-Object { $_.whenChanged -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) } ) {
    Write-Host "The Object is $($SamAccountName) - Created as at $($adObject.whenCreated.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt')) - Modified as at $($adObject.whenChanged.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt'))"
} Else {
    Write-Host " Error: AD object '$($SamAccountName)' not found!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

However, the result from the above is all object without the strict within 15 minutes time window?

Comment: `$15MinutesAgo` is a `[timespan]` object. why do you expect that to compare to your `$_.whenChanged`? that item looks like a `[datetime]` object ... and those two don't directly compare.

Comment: Not sure, that's why I am asking in this forum to assist me.
I just need to get the AD Object that was modified in the past 15 minutes range maximum.

Comment: Change `Where-Object { $_.whenChanged -lt $15MinutesAgo }` to `Where-Object { $_.whenChanged -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) }`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, thanks for the suggestion, however it is still returning the AD account that was modified longer than 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer it should be -gt to get the last 15minutes. $_.whenChanged -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer - it looks like folks have pointed out how to use the datetime objects. great! [*grin*]

Comment: that's great. thank you, everyone :-)